# How to handle foreign key association in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I already associated user and userAddresses table.properly worked but recently i removed autoincrement in userAddresses table .Because address_id now set UUID (varchar) thats why remove autoincrement.

My code like:

```
return myModel.user.create(userInfo, {
          include: [{
            model: myModel.userAddresses,
            as: 'addresses'
          }]
        }).then((insertUser) => {

          return "insert successfully"
        }).catch((err) => {

          throw err;
        });
```

Error Like:"SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: ADDRESS_ID cannot be null"

Answer (score 0):

You have to verify your model class in node js "myModel.userAddresses" whether property allow null is true

```
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
allowNull: true
```

Comment: Thanks siva but my case in postman i give data like this

{  
   "users":{  
     
      "addresses":[  
         {  
         
            "COUNTRY_ID":null,         
            "CITY":"",
            "POSTCODE":"",
            "customerId":"4f4b4643-21b5-44b9-b396-a7afbd7e9544",
            "STATE":"",
            "ADDRESS_1":"mmm1 address",
            "ADDRESS_ID":10,
            "ADDRESS_2":""
         }
      ],

  "ID":"4f4b4643-21b5-44b9-b396-a7afbd7e9544",  
      "FIRSTNAME":"testuser",
      "EMAIL":"mmm@gmail.com",
     
   }
}

Comment: inside the nodejs i log (console.log) the address details not show ADDRESS_ID but show all other fields

Comment: siva any idea about why not show ADDRESS_ID in inside the nodejs

Comment: Not sure. May be model class property name typo error / mismatch

Comment: But we set autoincrement to ADDRESS_ID its work properly

Comment: in that has your are not listed ADDRESS_ID in model property list . Just add a 'ADDRESS_ID' ,with type and allow null property  or  Just show me your model class. I can check